# Opening MS Word maximized

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Each time I open my MS Word, it is not in its largest size. I want it to me maximized when being opened. How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Press the Maximize button to make it full screen, then hold down the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> down and click the close button.

This trick will store the current position in the windows registry and that will be restored the next time you open a program.

This works with most programs actually.

So long story short, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+close program, is a way to force save the current position of a program.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution I can think of is to create a shortcut for Microsoft Word and in the shortcut properties, set it to always run **Maximized**.

Better yet, change the shortcut for **Word 2010** in this location:

```
%PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office 2010
```

In the shortcut properties, make this change:

[image: Word shortcut properties]

and click **OK**.